# Counterexamples in metric spaces about density

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I came across those questions on my school's topological dynamical-system textbook and I had totally no idea about them.

> (a) There exist a compact metric space $X$, a homeomorphism $f:X\rightarrow X$ and a point $x_0\in X$, such that
>   $$\text{Orb}_f(x_0)={\{f^k(x_0):k\in\mathbb{Z}\}}$$
>   is dense in $X$ while ${\{f^k(x):k\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}}$ and ${\{f^k(x):k\in\mathbb{Z}^-\}}$ are not dense in $X$ for any $x\in X$.
>
> (b) There exist a metric space $X$ with countable many open dense subset $\{U_i\}$, s.t. $\bigcap_{i}U_i=\varnothing$.

Thanks to Henno Brandsma, now we have (b):

Consider $X=\mathbb{Q}(=\{r_i\}_{-\infty}^{+\infty})$ as the subspace of $\mathbb{E}^1$ and $U_i=X-\{r_i\}$. Clearly, every $U_i$ is open since $U^c_i=\{r_i\}$ is a point set which is closed. To see the density of $U_i$, it is sufficient to show that $U_i$ is not closed. In fact, sequence $\{r_i+\frac{1}{n}\}\subset X$ converges to $\{r_i\}\notin U_i$, which implies that $U_i$ is not closed.

EDITED! Sorry I've given the (a) incorrectly and now it is clarified.
The first version is wrong because that $\bigcup_{x\in X}{\{f^k(x):k\in\mathbb{Z}^-\}}=X$ and $\bigcup_{x\in X}\text{Orb}_f(x)=X$ always holds.

Additional Question:

> (b)$^\prime$ Determine whether it is possible that there exist a metric space $X$ with countable many open dense subset $\{U_i\}$, such that for any $i\neq j$, $U_i\cap U_j=\varnothing$ holds.

Just now I figured out (b)$^\prime$:

If for any $i\neq j$, $U_i\cap U_j=\varnothing$, we will have $U_i\subset X-U_j$. Then $\overline{U_i}\subset X-U_j$ because $X-U_j$ is closed. Clearly $X-U_j$ is a proper subset of $X$, which implies $\overline{U_i}\neq X$.

Comment: B: the rationals will give an example.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How can rationals open

Comment: In $X=\mathbb{Q}$ all sets of the form $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{q\}$ are open and dense.

Comment: They're dense as no singleton $\{q\}$ in $\Bbb Q$ is isolated.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma many thanks

Comment: And what is $f^0$? The identity?

Comment: @PaulFrost yes $f^0=\textrm{id}_X$.

Comment: @PaulFrost sorry but the first version for (a) was wrong and I have just corrected it.

Comment: As to the new (b)': if $U_i$ is (open and) dense and $U_j$ is open (non-empty) we must have $U_i \cap U_j \neq \emptyset$. So any pair of non-empty open dense sets intersects (and the intersection is again dense and open). So even 2 sets fails, and this holds in any topological space (no metric needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X = \{-1, 1 \} \cup \{ \frac{n}{1+ \lvert n \rvert}  : n \in \mathbb Z \}$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$. Let $x_n =  \frac{n}{1+\lvert n \rvert}$. Define
$f : X \to X, f(-1) = -1, f(1) = 1, f(x_n) = x_{n+1}$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. This is a homeomorphism. You have $f^k(x_0) = x_k$. Thus
$$\text{Orb}_f(x_0) = \{ \frac{n}{1+\lvert n \rvert}  : n \in \mathbb Z \}$$
which is dense in $X$ and
$${\{f^k(x):k\in\mathbb{Z}^\pm\}} = \{ \frac{n}{1+\lvert n \rvert}  : n \in \mathbb Z^\pm \}$$
which are not dense in $X$.

Comment: Why Orb$_f(x_0)$ is dense in $X$? I think $\{1\}$ is isolated because $\frac{n}{1+n^2}\leq\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Lau the example has been corrected. And we need isolated points anyway (all the $x_n$ are) because if $X$ is compact metric and without isolated points and there is a point with a dense full orbit, there is also a point with a dense forward orbit.

Comment: many thanks again

Comment: You are right, I had to correct the definition so that $x_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ and $x_n \to -1$ as $n \to -\infty$.